# TypoScript: override COA if empty

Tags: arrays, object, typo3, overriding, typoscript

I have 2 COAs: `lib.productContent` and `lib.categoryContent` which contain data from a user function.
I also have a third COA - `lib.seoColumns` - which should contain by default the product COA. If the product COA is empty, it should be overridden by the category COA, but I don't know how to actually check if the product COA is empty:

```
########## PRODUCT CONTENT ##########
lib.productContent = COA
lib.productContent {
    10 = USER
    10 {
        userFunc = Vendor\Provider\UserFunc\Page->getPageContentByAlias
        alias = TEXT
        alias.data = GP:product
        aliasField.cObject = TEXT
        aliasField.cObject.value = product_alias
    }
}

########## CATEGORY CONTENT ##########
lib.categoryContent = COA
lib.categoryContent {
    10 = USER
    10 {
        userFunc = Vendor\Provider\UserFunc\Page->getPageContentByAlias
        alias = TEXT
        alias.data = GP:category
        aliasField.cObject = TEXT
        aliasField.cObject.value = category_alias
    }
}

########## SEO COLUMNS ##########
lib.seoColumns = COA
lib.seoColumns {
    10 < lib.productContent
    10.stdWrap.override.cObject < lib.categoryContent

    # 10.stdWrap.override.if    <-- IF WHAT ?

    wrap = <seoColumns><![CDATA[|]]></seoColumns>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way would be to use the stdWrap **.ifEmpty** function
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#ifempty

```
lib.seoColumns = COA
lib.seoColumns {
   10. < lib.productContent
   10.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject < lib.categoryContent
   wrap = <seoColumns><![CDATA[|]]></seoColumns>
}
```

as ifEmpty is of type string/stdWrap it supports stdWrap Attributes and we can use .cObject to load another Content Object. like the COA for the second case.

Comment: Should be working as well, but there is stdWrap missing between 10 and ifEmpty, since COA does not provide stdWrap on the top level.

Comment: thanks @Joey for pointing out the missing stdWrap i fixed it.

Comment: Just the other way around - 10.stdWrap.ifEmpty ;-)

Comment: This is the final working snippet: 10.stdWrap.ifEmpty.cObject < lib.categoryContent

Comment: Could this please be corrected in the actual snippet, since the comment might be unrecognized?

Answer (score 2):

Just do it the other way around, since override only will do the actual override, when there is at least something in the overriding object.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#override

```
########## SEO COLUMNS ##########
lib.seoColumns = COA
lib.seoColumns {
  10 < lib.categoryContent
  10.stdWrap.override.cObject < lib.productContent
  wrap = <seoColumns><![CDATA[|]]></seoColumns>
}
```

no *if* necessary.